# Forward declaration of templated function pointer (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I have a number of function pointers declared in a header file where the functions the pointers point to are assigned in a cpp file (depending on endianness).

For the non-template functions I just declare them as extern and everything works fine, like so:

**parse.h**

```
extern int32(*parseWord)(byte**);
```

**parse.cpp**

```
int32(*parseWord)(byte**) = IS_BIG_ENDIAN ? &pWordBE : &pWordLE;
```

For templated function pointers I assumed I could do the same:

**parse.h**

```
template<typename T>
extern T(*parse)(byte**);
```

**parse.cpp**

```
template<typename T>
T (*parse)(byte**) = IS_BIG_ENDIAN ? &pBE<T> : &pLE<T>;
```

But the above results in undefined references.

Is there a way of doing this kind of forward declaration?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `template <typename T> using parse = std::conditional_t<IS_BIG_ENDIAN, decltype(&pBE<T>), decltype(&pLE<T>)>;` and put it in the header?

Comment: I'm an old fashioned C guy and a lot of newer C++ stuff has passed me by so I'll have to research std::conditional<> and decltype - thanks for your input

Comment: If you still want `parse` to be a value in a translation unit, you will have to use inline variables from C++17 and explicit instantiations.

Comment: The reason why you are getting undefined references is ultimately that templates have to be implemented in the header file, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: I wanted to avoid that because apart from being a bit ugly (imo) it also seems a bit fragile

Comment: Then you have to find out how to make `parse` *not* a template.